# UI-Bootstrap Number Input Spinner

Tags: angularjs, input, angular-directive

***What I want:***

[image: Input number spinner with great-looking buttons that you can always see]

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" spinner ng-model="$scope.someNumber"/>
<!-- notice the `spinner` directive -->
```

***What I have:***

[image: Normal input with ui-bootstrap. Spinner is hidden and tiny.]

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="$scope.someNumber"/>
```

Are there directives for better number spinners?

I've tried searching Google, but I'm not finding anything (*spinner* is also used to refer to a loading image, so perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a directive special for you:

You can customize it as you want

```
  <number-spin data-ng-model="vm.testNumber"></number-spin>
```

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/84qxvgm8/)

P.S. I added directive to npmjs here the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-number-spin),

also [github](https://github.com/falendary/ng-number-spin/tree/gh-pages) and [demos](http://falendary.github.io/ng-number-spin/example/)